# Expanded wrapped with a GestureDetector inside a Row no longer expands

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm experiencing some layout issues using a GestureDetector in a Row.

This is the build method of my Widget:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final dateFormat = new DateFormat('dd/MM/yyyy');

List<Widget> children = [
  Text(
    todo.content,
    style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, color: Colors.white),
    overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
  )
];
if (todo.date != null) {
  children.add(Text(
    dateFormat.format(todo.date!),
    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey),
  ));
}

return Container(
    height: 50.0,
    color: backgroundColour,
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: todoVMargin),
    child: Row(
      children: [
        Theme(
            data: ThemeData(unselectedWidgetColor: Colors.white),
            child: TokidokiCheckbox(
                value: todo.checked,
                onChanged: (bool value) {
                  markChecked(value);
                })),
        Expanded(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: children,
          ),
        ),
        ReorderableDragStartListener(
          index: todoIndex,
          child: SizedBox(
              width: 32.0,
              height: 32.0,
              child: Image.asset(
                'assets/icons/drag_handle.png',
              )),
        )
      ],
    ));
}
```

And this is what my row looks like with this setup:

[image]

Needing the area between my checkbox and the drag handle to be interacted with via a double tap, I thought wrapping the Expanded widget with a GestureDetector would do the trick, and so wrapped it as follows:

```
GestureDetector(
  child: Expanded(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: children,
    ),
  ),
  onDoubleTap: onDoubleTap,
),
```

But this is what my row looks like now:

[image]

The Expanded widget no longer expands and the layout breaks. I tried wrapping the Column instead, but the result is that only the text part is tappable, as the Column does not naturally expand to take all the available space.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add `behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,` in `GestureDetector` and everything would work fine. Also, wrap `GestureDetector` with `Expanded`.

Example code:

```
Expanded(
    child: GestureDetector(
    behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
    onTap: () {
        print('Tapped');
    },
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: children,
         ),
     ),
),
```